# Identify answers that just copy content from the question and say nothing more

Tags: feature-request, new-users, not-an-answer, plagiarism, welcoming

I flagged a (now-deleted) answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827817/how-group-by-having-limit-works/54289904#54289904) as NAA, because it was literally nothing more than the code snippet copied from the question, and pasted into the answer box. It was identical, except that the formatting was removed.

I am all too aware that the opinion of moderators is that anything that could conceivably be answer to an on-topic question is considered an answer, so I wasn't entirely surprised that my flag was rejected. I had, though, commented explaining that the 'answer' was purely a partial copy of the question, but apparently that still wasn't good enough to persuade a moderator that it wasn't an answer. It baffles me, but that argument seems to have no winners, so not what I'm asking here.

I feel like this is a pattern I've seen a few times, where a new user for no obvious reason just copies some or all of a question into the answer box. Perhaps it's a mistake? Perhaps they think they're doing something worthwhile? Perhaps they're just experimenting with the system and don't know what they're doing? Or do you get points or a badge or something for posting your first answer? I don't know why - but it's fairly obviously never anything useful.

So - it seems like it would be a super-trivial feature to implement to gently nudge a new user (or any user) who's answer is an exact copy of some or all of the question (excluding formatting) into not doing that, or at least adding some explanation.

I know that getting feature requests implemented is extremely unlikely, but I feel like this could help towards the Welcome Wagon stuff, because preventing new users from (accidentally or on purpose) posting garbage will avoid them receiving an unfriendly comment in response (*whispers: no matter how much they might deserve it*)

Comment: I'd like to see some data on how common this actually is and hear from moderators about if they encounter it often. I suspect that we wouldn't find many non-deleted examples of it, meaning that either it's not common or moderators would be handling them often enough to know it's very common.

Comment: Personally never saw that. We cannot create a feature for each corner case.

Comment: I take your point, I guess I'm thinking of it more like a static analysis tool in building software - it doesn't take many times of having to manually point something out in a code review before I wonder whether something couldn't automatically look out for the same problem.

Answer (score 22):

Whenever I see these kinds of wastes of the answer box, I always wonder why people think it's a reasonable use of the answer feature. There's no reward to doing it here, but there are some Q&A sites where simply providing answers is rewarded, resulting in crap answers being posted to random questions (Yahoo Answers jumps to mind, though there are others) that make no sense but vaguely look like they could be an answer by copying terms or segments from the question.

These kinds of answers should be deleted, however the NAA flag isn't likely to get a good result. The Not An Answer flag should be used for things that are obviously not answers, such that someone unfamiliar with the technology can look at it out of context and say "That's not an answer."

However, if there is something tricky about it, such as the answer is simply plagiarizing the question with no attempt at an answer, then out of context it still looks like it could be an answer, which leads to the flag getting declined in most cases.

In this case, a custom mod flag would be more appropriate, saying something like "This answer is just a copy of the code snippet from the question without any changes or explanation or attempt at an answer." That way, the mod can know exactly what they're looking for and check easily that it's not an answer. The mod will also be able to check if the user has a habit of doing that too and hand out a suspension if they deem fit, or give some more gentle nudging like your feature request if they prefer, so it's a win-win to raise the custom flag.

I don't think a new feature is necessary to handle these kinds of answers since we already have the custom moderator flags which should serve the same purpose.

Comment: I rather thought that this would be the answer I'd get. And I understand, but I prefer to use custom flags for truly difficult scenarios. I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that mods can see the comments under the answer that's flagged, and that they might read them. That felt like the better solution, because if the OP has made a genuine mistake, they might fix it before the mod even comes along to look, resolving the issue without a mod needing to deal with a custom flag.

Comment: I feel like it would still be a worthwhile feature though, because why waste moderators' time on something that can very easily be automated? Also, it's a very useful teaching opportunity for a user, where they can have the explanation provided to them right away, at the point they're trying to post garbage.

Comment: Good point - poor choice of words on my part. As for how easy to automate, I think simply taking the question text, without formatting, and testing whether the answer text also without formatting exists within the question text would have found this example. I've no idea how many other examples of this there are - perhaps it's so few as to be not worth bothering with. It feels like such a trivial solution though, that the cost would be minimal, so only needs minimal benefit to be worthwhile. I gather that SO are hiring tons of new developers - seems like a good feature for a new team member :)

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave The system does have checks for automatically detecting if a user posts the same thing repeatedly. The question might be how many resources it would require to check for answers that copy the code from a question verbatim. Another issue is the change of formatting - in some languages (e.g, Haskell and Python) indentation has meaning. In those languages, a change of formatting may be the answer to an OP's question.

Comment: @S.L.Barth - oh yes, good point! Still, it seems like one of the many algorithms for determining the similarity of two pieces of text might be a candidate, which could be run on the client and pop up a hint saying something like "You seem to be saying something very similar to the content of the question, are you sure that's what you want to do? It's better if you include your own description, see here for what constitutes a good answer".

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I did end up contradicting myself when I was thinking of the answer in a more productive way, it wouldn't be that hard to check, just something like "If entire text of answer is contained in question, prevent posting and display error." I was thinking highly similar blocks of text like when an [answer quotes the code to point out the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10392844/7795130) would result in too many edge cases to be worthwhile, but if we just go the simple route of seeing the answer contains nothing that isn't in the question, then that won't have any false positives.